# change value to corresponding value from another column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i have a data frame that looks as following

```
     col1 col2 col3
0   a     d    0
1   b     e    1
2   c     f    0
3   x     t    1
.................
```

i want to change col3 with value 1 to corresponding value in col2

the result would be

```
   col1 col2 col3
0   a     d    0
1   b     e    e
2   c     f    0
3   x     t    t
.................

df[['col1','col2','col3']].applymap(lambda x: df['col2'] if x==1 else x)
```

the above gives error somehow

any one have idea how to do it with pandas?

Comment: what the error you gets ?

Comment: TypeError: ("'int' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index value')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df.loc[df.col3 == 1, 'col3'] = df.col2
```

Or:

```
df.col3 = df.col3.mask(df.col3 == 1, df.col2)
#df.col3 = df.col3.where(df.col3 != 1, df.col2)
#df.col3 = np.where(df.col3 == 1, df.col2, df.col3)

print (df)
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    d    0
1    b    e    e
2    c    f    0
3    x    t    t
```

EDIT:

Slowier solution with `apply + lambda`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x['col2'] if x['col3']==1 else x, axis=1)
```

**Timings**:

```
#[40000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [42]: %timeit df.col3 = np.where(df.col3 == 1, df.col2, df.col3)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.97 ms per loop

In [43]: %timeit df.loc[df.col3 == 1, 'col3'] = df.col2
100 loops, best of 3: 6.81 ms per loop

In [44]: %timeit df.col3 = df.col3.mask(df.col3 == 1, df.col2)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.95 ms per loop

In [45]: %timeit df.col3 = df.col3.where(df.col3 != 1, df.col2)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.8 ms per loop

In [47]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x['col2'] if x['col3']==1 else x, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.39 s per loop
```

Comment: thank you, tested work, what if i have to use lambda ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but slowier I guess. Give me a sec.

Comment: @ikel - I add timings to my answer for compare solutions.